# How can I call function with current function name in C, C++?

Tags: c++, c, macros

before start, sorry for my poor English.
Environment:
c, c++, VS2019, after C99

Problem:
I have to call functions which have named with prefix with callee name.
I have many callee and variable prefix, so I want to handle it macro in preprocess-time for convenience with coding.

I tried:

> 

```
`void prefix_function_name();
 void function_name(){
     (prefix_##__func__)();
 }
`
```

I know it can't be possible, cause **func** is const char[].

So I need to
: get function name with a token not a string.
or
: turn a string into a token.
ex)

> 

```
void foo(); const char[] a = "foo"; 
a();
```

Is anyone have solution?

---

Here's my actual problem.

I have many functions with C code.
And I'm going to make test code with gtest(C++).
And I need to use mock(or stub. anyway) for functions.
But, there is no way to call mock function instead of original function.
So I need to make hook like this

> 

```
`extern "C" void mock_foo();
 void foo(){
     return mock_foo(); // hook
     ... // actual code
 }
`
```

To avoid miss typing and human error, I wanted to make macro that makes hook for functions.
Now I'm using macro like this. (Not in detail)

> 

```
`#define MACRO(func_name) return mock_##func_name();
 void foo(){
     MACRO(foo) // hook
     ... // actual code
 }
`
```

And I wanted to get rid of typing function name.

Here's my actual problem. Is there any way?

Comment: what langauge is this? Please pick one. And this looks like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need this? How is `(prefix_##__func__)();` (assuming it would work) any better than `prefix_function_name()` ?

Comment: i mean inside `function_name` the name of the current function is always `function_name` no macros or runtime effects can change that

Comment: Why not just hardcode it? Explain your full scenario

Comment: i guess its one of the lessons one has to learn the hard way: Macros are not convenient for coding, rather the opposite. It took me a while to get convinced, because at first they look pretty cool

Comment: I second the above comments: you probably try to solve your problem a wrong way. Please describe the actual problem, only _then_ an appropriate way to solve it can be chosen.

Comment: I work with several people, and I want to make macro that my people can use easily.
There are many function, and we should make many test functions. And if I can handle this, many of things can be done with macro.

Comment: We want to insert some code that have strictly fixed and containing function name.
For example, 
void foo(){
    call_new_foo();  // insert thing. call_new_foo(); is already defined. name foo will be variable
    ...  // oringinal code things
}

If there is no way, we can hardcode it. I just want to know there is smarter way

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it the way you describe, since there is no way to turn a string (variable or literal) into a token.   You might try a macro that defines your calling function, such as

```
#define DEFINE_FUNCTION(prefix, name)  void name () { prefix ##_ ##name ();}
```

and use it

```
void foo_func() {std::cout << "foo_func()\n";}     // assume <iostream> has been included

DEFINE_FUNCTION(foo, func)           // note no ; here

int main()
{
     func();       
}
```

This will work since `DEFINE_FUNCTION(foo, func)` has defined `func()` so it calls `foo_func()`.

**Generally I would strongly advise against doing the above**.   It may seem convenient to you now to use a macro, rather than defining your functions by hand.    It will not seem so convenient in future when you, or someone else, is maintaining/extending the code - particularly if some of the functions needs to do things slightly differently than the macro sets up.  Your code will quickly become a mess in that case.

Comment: Yes. Maybe I should use more manpower. 
I can use #define MACRO(prefix, funcname)
instead of #define MACRO(prefix).
I just wanted to use "\_\_func\_\_" instead of manpower.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want this:

```
void prefix_function_name();
#define INVOKER_FUNCTION(name) \
void name () {\
   prefix_##name();\
}

INVOKER_FUNCTION(function_name);
```

Comment: The OP wants to use a C-string as the function name, so this answer is probably not the case.

Comment: @M.Zhang - That's not what the OP asked for.   The question is about how to get `func()` to call `prefix_func()`.    The description in terms of a string literal is because the OP's first thought was to use the `__func__` predefined macro (which gives a nul terminated string) to recover the name of the function as a token - and even the OP admits that is not possible.

Comment: Peter is right. I already have function and want to call other function in the function with the function name.

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid, you have selected slightly-not-suitable language (i mean C++).
But,
You can do this (in C++) by using dll-s:

- pack your functions into external library (.dll, .so).
- then you can load library and export function by name and call it. See boost::dll:import_alias (for crossplatform code), LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress (for Windows).

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it would be too load. I just wanted to make macro for convenience. Repeatedly, thanks for answering. I would find this later.